# How to upgrade JDK 1.6 to a higher version to run Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 installed on my mac and trying to start Glassfish server but it shows the following error,

```
GlassFish server could not be started with JDK 1.6 (Default). Please sleect another Java SE 
Platform.
```

I have downloaded and installed jdk-7u25-macosx-x64.dmg and running java -version shows the following

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I try to choose a new platform for my netbeans and get to JavaVirtualMachines folder there is only 1.6.0.jdk in this folder!

How can I point it to use 1.7 version?

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is only looking in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. You have to tell it where you installed the JDK.

1) Download the JDK7 from here: [Oracle JDK7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (based on your question, you've already done this step, but I'm putting it here for others who come here looking for help)

2) Install it with the default settings.

3) Return to where you got the above error (while trying to start glassfish) and click Manage Platforms again.

4) Navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home and select it.